# converting binary image to gray scale image in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I working on Optical Character Recognition system.

I want to convert the license plate image from binary to gray scale.

let's look at the next example:

this is the binary image:

[image]

and this is the gray scale:

[image]

what I want to know is if there is a way to convert it from binary to the gray, or this is not possible because i've lost the information when I converted the picture to binary at the beginning.

any idea how to do this? thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "grayscale"? A binary image only has black and white in it, so where do you expect the gray values to come from? Are you wanting to do some kind of filtering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert a binary image of class `logical` to a grayscale image of class `double`, you simply call

```
double(yourBinaryImage)
```

**EDIT**

To *revert* from a binary image to the grayscale image you had before thresholding is impossible without the grayscale image, since by thresholding you have dropped all the grayscale texture information.

Comment: I try this already and I didn't saw any change. the image is still looks like black and white. thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Michael: The information in the grayscale image is the same as in the binary image, so there should not be any change after transformation. However, the grayscale image can now take on arbitrary values between 0 and 1. For example, if you write `myImage(1:5,1:5) = 0.5`, then you'll see gray in the top left corner.

Comment: If I have a binary image having all zeros and ones, how can I convert it to a grayscale having zeros as zeros and ones as 255? So that I can concatenate a binary image with a grayscale image and save for comparison? Kindly reply urgently.

Comment: @FarazAhmad: comments are not a good place to answer questions. Just hit the "ask a question" button next time. Anyway: Multiply the binary image by 255, and you're done (though depending on the class of the other grayscale image, you may have to convert to uint8 as well)

Comment: I am multiplying by 255 but still they are zeros and ones, but I did not convert to uint8. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use the distance transform to achieve a gray scale image from a binary image. In MATLAB, try bwdist or something like that.
The result, of course, will not be the original gray scale image.

Comment: any thoughts on anti aliasing resampling done by yan le cunn to convert binary images to grayscale.

Answer (score 1):

**My old answer:**
I think you cannot exactly get the grayscale image which you have shown from the binary image. What you can do is convert the image into grayscale and then do gaussian noising to spread the edge and then you can also add random noise to the whole image. So, now your new grayscale image will look a lot different than binary image.

**Update:** You can also train an autoencoder (AE) which map binarised images to grayscale images. So, if you have say 200 images of license plates in grayscale and binarised formats, now you can try training an AE which takes input the binarised image and output the grayscale image. I would suggest to start with simple AE architecture which you can get from many open source platforms. For ex: https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html is a very simple architecture to implement AE. Based on the results, you can see if it works or not. If it seems to work, then you have play with the architecture and hyperparameters to improve the binarised to grayscale conversion. **Of course, it will not be the original grayscale image. But it can be a more realistic grayscale image**